# Set Console as full screen and max size in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to set a Console Window as full screen and my current code isn't working
    Module Module1

```
Sub Main()
    Console.WindowHeight = Console.LargestWindowHeight
    Console.WindowWidth = Console.LargestWindowWidth
    Console.SetBufferSize(Console.LargestWindowWidth, Console.LargestWindowHeight)
    Console.SetWindowPosition(Console.LargestWindowWidth / 2, Console.LargestWindowHeight / 2)
    Console.Read()
End Sub

End Module
```

System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException was unhandled
  Message=The window position must be set such that the current window size fits within the console's buffer, and the numbers must not be negative.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you're using VBA? `System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException` sound more like VB.Net to me...

Comment: Oh. Oops. Yeah. It's VB.NET

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.setwindowposition.aspx) gives the answer you seek:

> ArgumentOutOfRangeException :
>   left + WindowWidth is greater than BufferWidth.
>   or
>   top + WindowHeight is greater than BufferHeight.

So you should set the window position to 0, 0.